# RuntimeError in Jupyter Kernel Gateway on Docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, jupyter-notebook

When I try to execute Jupyter Kernel Gateway on Docker, I get the below error:

2017-08-03T11:00:51.732015249Z [KernelGatewayApp] Kernel shutdown: 27351426-2078-4101-b3f3-86da41d6e141
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735665285Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735690921Z   File "/opt/conda/bin/jupyter-kernelgateway", line 11, in 
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735699387Z     sys.exit(launch_instance())
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735705691Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735711902Z     return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735717618Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 591, in launch_instance
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735723686Z     app.initialize(argv)
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735731330Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kernel_gateway/gatewayapp.py", line 212, in initialize
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735737468Z     self.init_configurables()
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735742836Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kernel_gateway/gatewayapp.py", line 241, in init_configurables
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735748923Z     self.kernel_pool = KernelPool(self.prespawn_count, self.kernel_manager)
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735755996Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kernel_gateway/services/kernels/pool.py", line 27, in **init**
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735762895Z     kernel_id = kernel_manager.start_kernel(kernel_name=self.kernel_manager.parent.seed_notebook['metadata']['kernelspec']['name'])
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735772782Z   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kernel_gateway/services/kernels/manager.py", line 71, in start_kernel
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735779471Z     raise RuntimeError('Error seeding kernel memory')
2017-08-03T11:00:51.735785063Z RuntimeError: Error seeding kernel memory

Comment: too less details and that too not well formatted as code. Give more details of how you are running and where you are running it

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to compile errors in the respective notebook.

To try, I commented everything and just annotated a single cell with a GET request.

It worked!